# Error occurred when execute the jar file

Tags: java

I have jar file. When i execute it through command prompt then error is showing "no main manifest attribute, in agent .jar ".
I added manifest. Again same error is showing.

Comment: pleaase show us You manifest.xml

Comment: You will need to give us more information than that, so that we can help you better. What does your manifest file look like? What does your main class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't bundled a `Manifest.mf` inside the `/META-INF` folder of your Jar or your `Manifest.mf` doesn't specify your Jar's entry point with

```
Main-Class: com.your.apps.MainClass
```

A typical manifest looks like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.your.apps.MainClass
Class-Path: dependency-1.jar dependency-2.jar
```